# django list_filter in html

Tags: django, django-filter

[image]

How do i import this list_filter into my html? do you have any documentation that easy to follow and easy to understand? is it possible?

```
class ArticleListView(ListView):

    model = StudentsEnrollmentRecord
    s=StudentsEnrollmentRecord.objects.all()
    paginate_by = 50  # if pagination is desired
    searchable_fields = ["Student_Users", "id", "Section"]
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use template tags to loop your object and populate your html:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/

To give you a kickstart:

```
<ul>

{% for filter in s %}

<li>{{ filter.Student_Users }}</li>

{% endfor %}

</ul>
```

This will basically create one `<li>` per each item in your queryset.
Make sure that the required data is returned properly from your view via the context:

```
context = {
        'queryset': s,    
    }
    return (context)
```

Comment: I just i copy this code into my html but nothing happen

Comment: I don't know your model, but make sure that the objects are returned by your view accordingly.